# Table with vertical scroll and pages for horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table that have important information in left column and in the top row, therefore these should always be visible, I then want to have Pages in the bottem for horizontal "scrolling" and a normal scroll for vertical scrolling.

Is there a Jquery script that supports this?

It would look something like this
[image]

Comment: how about `overflow:scroll` ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? (I used CSS, not jQuery, sorry)

http://jsfiddle.net/mAnQp/

Update: added pages
http://jsfiddle.net/mAnQp/3/

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to display basic data then you could use one of the Jquery plugins available for this purpose like [Datatables](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/index.html). They are very flexible and you could do most of the basic things using one of their extra's.

If your requirement is more than just displaying data. It has complex edits, custom features for each column and stuff then your better of with a custom implementation. We've build such a table which has integrated autopopulates, calendar and other completely custom features by having a div float beside the table and using Jquery to control the scroll. The header and the frozen column on the left are usually separate tables/divs themselves and are just aligned as per the table using Jquery. They work quite well for IE 8+ and other browsers.

Comment: My data consist only of Checkboxes, with names in the column and pages the header and that controls which pages a user has access to (I havent made it, I am just trying to make it more useable)

Comment: You could easily use datatables to display your data. This link provides information on adding checkboxes to your table (http://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html).